# Hundreds of Jquery & JS errors in Dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, jquery, dreamweaver

I'm very much still learning web development and I am completely stumped.
I use Dreamweaver and my current project is in Bootstrap.

Suddenly, the JQuery library and bootstrap.js are FULL of errors. 
I have not so much as touched either file or edited them in anyway.

Some example errors include these from jquery:

```
Expected '===' and instead saw '=='

Expected '{' and instead saw 'throw'

Missing a semi-colon
```

And these from JS:

```
'$' is defined but never used

Misleading line break before '+'; readers may interpret this as an expression boundary

Expected '}' to match '{' from line 38 and instead saw ';'
```

There are hundreds of these errors.
I contacted Adobe who explicitly told me the following:

"We want to inform you that errors are not due to Dreamweaver.
Files mentioned by you are the files created by bootstrap development team. If you go to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/ and download bootstraps files for 3.3.7 you will find the same errors in there. We would request you to contact bootstrap development team regarding the same as it is not associated with Dreamweaver."

Before I go down the next wormhole, I would like to know if anyone else is experiencing this problem?
How did you fix it?
I'm still learning and am feeling very confused by what to do next, some advice from someone experienced would be most welcome.

Thanks

Comment: These aren't errors; they're lint warnings (most likely JSLint). Basically the jQuery/BS code doesn't match the set of syntax rules that DW is apparently applying. You should ignore these warnings for 3rd-party libraries. There might also be an option to turn linting off, but you might not want to do that.

Comment: Find the settings that don't check linting errors/warnings in those external libraries so you can focus only on your own code. Don't bother contacting either one...both are heavily used in millions of sites

Comment: Just a suggestion - Stop using Dreamweaver - get yourself a copy of an editor like Notepad++ and learn how to create the HTML / CSS / JS / Bootstrap layout yourself. - You will learn more and become a better coder.

Comment: Have a look here : https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1874127

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about the usage/configuration of Dreamweaver. There is no coding issue here.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and suggestions. This is still an issue for me. I literally do not know what to do. I built a carousel and dropdown menu using bootstrap. These used to work. They now do not because when the JS is called, the errors prevent them from working.  Changing from Dreamweaver to Notepad isn't going to be viable in the middle of this project I'm afraid.